# detect input value length on focus

Tags: jquery, input, detect

When the user start to type inside of the `input` I would like the input to do something, so I have tried to write it like this:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
  if ( $('input').val().length > 0 ) {
    $('input').css('color', 'red');
  }
  else {
    $('input').css('color', 'blue');
  }
});
```

Just to get the Idea how to detect when the `input` isn't empty
 What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9o1p0v/)

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ) {
    $(this).css('color', 'blue');
  }
  else {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Comment: You forgot about paste and change events:

    `$('input').on("change paste keyup", function(){...});`

Comment: Thanks, I don't really know all the stuff that you wrote on the comment, but i figured that my mistake was that I use the `focus` instead of the `keyup`

Comment: You're currently checking if key was pressed by user, but he can also paste it or change it by triggering other events. Just change .keyup() to .on("change paste keyup") and you'll have them handled.
http://jsfiddle.net/rq9o1p0v/1/

Comment: if youre agree with my answer please accept my answer @user4571629

Comment: I totally agree with it, Thank you so much!